# Not able to concatenate a variable to contain string from XML

Tags: php, xml, concatenation

I have this XML file

```
<response> 
 <rows>
   <row>
     <id>6899</id><Number>3</Number><Parent>No Parent</Parent><State>state</State>
     <DateFmt>27-AUG-2013</DateFmt>
   </row>
   <row>
     <id>5523</id><Number>3</Number><Parent>YES</Parent><State>state</State>
     <DateFmt>16-AUG-2013</DateFmt>
   </row>
   <row>
     <id>80193</id><Number>1</Number><Parent>NO</Parent><State>state</State>
     <DateFmt>18-SEP-2013</DateFmt>
   </row>
</rows>
```

I am using php to get the content simplexml_load_string()
and then 2 foreach loops to get to string inside xml
The code:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
if(!$xml) { 
  $errors .= "...";
   }else{                     
    foreach($xml->rows as $rows)
    {           
      foreach($rows->row as $row) 
       {                          
         if(isset($row->DateFmt) AND !empty($row->DateFmt))
           { 
         $DateFmt = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row->DateFmt)); //format the data to suit the MDB table structure  
         }else $DateFmt = "NULL"; //put null so the MySQL will recognize an empty set

   $Query .= "(
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row->id)."',   
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row->Number)."',   
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row->Parent)."',   
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($row->State)."',                        
        if ($DateFmt == 'NULL') $Query .= " NULL, "; 
        else $Query .= "'".$DateFmt."', ";
   }
}
```

The result stops at DateFmt and start over no metter how i try
this is the echo of the query variable.

```
( '6899', '3', 'No Parent', 'state', ( '5523', '3', 'YES', 'state', ( '8139', '1', 'NO', 'state',
```

Some help? It might be because of the null value?

If I print the datefmt from XML or the variable I get the right values

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not concatenating in the right way your `$Query` variable.

It should be like this (I have also supposed you want to close the bracket before the coma).

You shoud also check `date` command  is parsing your date in the right way and that there is something is `$DateFmt` variable.

```
$Query .= "(
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($row->id)."',   
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($row->Number)."',   
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($row->Parent)."',   
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($row->State)."',";

    if ($DateFmt == 'NULL'){
        $Query .= " NULL), "; 
    }
    elseif ($DateFmt == FALSE){
        $Query .= " NULL), "; //$DateFmt is not set because date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row->DateFmt)) failed
    }
    else{
        $Query .= "'".$DateFmt."'), ";
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - it doesn't work. Yes, the bracket must be closed, but that's not the problem - i am closing it after adding some more fields